# Как реализовать в python постоение эмперической функции распределения?

Tags: python

Мне необходимо реализовать построение эмперической функции распределения в данном виде [image]

Я пробовал использовать как canvas так и matplotlab, но проблема заключается в том, что диапазон необходимо считать именно от 0 до 1 используя данную выборку [-1.97, -0.736, -0.152, -0.049, -0.044, -0.029, 0.089, 0.306, 0.349, 0.413,
0.48, 0.518, 0.666, 0.691, 0.748, 0.834, 0.865, 0.866, 0.929, 0.974,
1.024, 1.096, 1.138, 1.197, 1.221, 1.258, 1.296, 0.426, 1.461, 1.537,
1.589, 1.679, 1.783, 1.833, 1.9, 1.922, 1.938, 1.954, 1.965, 1.976,
2.039, 2.047, 2.076, 2.261, 2.295, 2.453, 2.569, 2.604, 2.963, 3.031].
(т.е. результат который будет расчитан и отрисован должен выглядеть именно как в примере выше),
заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Что-то совсем непонятно, как относится выборка к осям графика. В выборке 50 значений, как они преобразуются в график? Ничего непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите вот тут. Вам там правильно ответили.
https://qna.habr.com/q/1074158

Comment: Тот ответ не подходит потому что мне необходимо чтобы функция была именно того вида что я дал в своем вопросе, в комментариях к тому ответу я объяснил почему именно тот ответ не подходит, не говоря о том что данный мне там ответ это скопированный ответ с другого вопроса на stackoverflow

Comment: Тогда объясните пожалуйста, что у вас отложено по оси Х (у вас почему-то "y") , учитывая что вы вроде бы рисуете эмпирическую функцию распределения?